# Homeomorphism between topological space and product space

Tags: general-topology, connectedness, product-space

Is there any connected topological space $X$ such that $X$ is homeomorphic to $X\times X$ ?

Comment: See also:
[Homeomorphism between Space and Product](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/677574/homeomorphism-between-space-and-product),
[Can a space $X$ be homeomorphic to its twofold product with itself, $X \times X$?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1384455/can-a-space-x-be-homeomorphic-to-its-twofold-product-with-itself-x-times-x),

Answer (score 3):

Yes, if $I$ is an infinite set and $Y$ any topological space, then $X = Y^I$ is homeomorphic to $X\times X$. If $Y$ is connected, so is $X$. A related but different example is given by the $\ell^p(\mathbb{N})$ spaces.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Take any infinite set equipped with the trivial topology. A singleton also has this property.

For a more interesting example, see: [Hilbert cube](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert_cube).

Answer (score 0):

For each natural number $i$ let $X_i=\mathbb R$ (we could choose any other connected space instead of $\mathbb R$) and define
$$
X=\prod_{i\in\mathbb N} X_i.
$$
Clearly $X$ is connected -- a product of connected spaces is always connected. The fact that $X\times X\cong X$ follows from the fact that, as sets, $\mathbb N\sqcup \mathbb N$ and $\mathbb N$ have the same cardinality (by $\mathbb N\sqcup \mathbb N$ I mean the union of two disjoint copies of $\mathbb N$). In fact, any bijection between $\mathbb N\sqcup \mathbb N$ and $\mathbb N$ induces a homeomorphism between $X\times X$ and $X$ by applying the bijection to indices.

Comment: You're right, but that's not relevant. I'm talking about $\mathbb N$ as an *index set*, not as a topological space.