# Can an n-ary cartesian product contain a copy of m-ary Cartesian product with m>n?

Tags: general-topology

Let $X$ be a completely regular topological space and $X^n$ its $n$-ary Cartesian product for positive integer $n$.

Let $V$ be a subset of $X^n$ which is homeomorphic to $X^m$.

Does it imply $m\leq n$?

I expect the answer to be simple, but at the moment I am stumped to find it, as well as I don't seem to find an existing solution for the question in this generality.

Comment: Hi, welcome to MSE. I think [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/355779/473276) fact answers your question.

Comment: @Izaak van Dongen's counterexample is much more complicated than it needs to be. One can directly see that $\mathbb N\cong\mathbb N^2$ since both are countable, discrete spaces.

Comment: Thank you! Do you know other examples?

Comment: I thought a bit about your question, and I must say that I expect this to basically never work. If you take a “random” topological space (or even completely regular Hausdorff), the product topology is frankly a mess. 
Your claim holds obviously for finite spaces, and it is a hard theorem that it holds for $\mathbb R$ (or any manifold). Other than that I could not find examples of your claim holding.

Comment: The two solutions are exactly what I was looking for. But out of curiosity: is there an if and only if theorem for this phenomenon? Meaning: "the implication stands if and only if X is ..." .

Comment: A related question is discussed [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3493139/topological-space-which-is-homeomorphic-to-its-square). This also gives a list of counterexamples to your claim. I do not know of an equivalent condition, but this is certainly an interesting question — likely a very hard one.

Comment: Yes, finite sets are obvious :) Discrete topology also. Thank you for the list! Rationals though are aleady ideally suited for my purpose.