# homeomophism from M to MxM

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, product-space

For an arbitrary (non discrete) metric space $M$, is $M$ never homeomorhpic to $M\times M$?

In my analysis class we learned that ${\mathbb{R}}$ is not homeomorhpic to $\mathbb{R}^{2}$ because if you remove the point (0) from each, ${\mathbb{R}}$ is unconnected while $\mathbb{R}^{2}$ stays connected. Does this hold in general for an arbitrary(non-discrete) metric space?

Comment: No. E.g., consider an infinite set with the discrete metric. PS. Please make your question self-contained, don't rely on the title to convey part of the question.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you mean. Shouldn't the title be conveying the question? Regardless, I was thinking of a non-discrete metric space

Comment: No. The title is just a headline. Some interfaces don't render formulas in the title readably. For another example, comsider an infinite dimensional Hilbert space.

Comment: What is always true is that continuous functions take connected sets to connected sets. That's what's being exploited in your example.

Comment: @LeoBell You can include the question in the title, but in that case you should **also** include the question in the body of your post.

Comment: See also: [Topological space which is homeomorphic to its square](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3493139), [Can a space $X$ be homeomorphic to its twofold product with itself, $X \times X$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1384455), [Homeomorphism between Space and Product: $X \cong X \times X$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/677574) and [Homeomorphism between topological space and product space](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/722412). (Those questions are about topological space, but there are some metrizable examples in the answers.)

Comment: Hey thanks everyone for the answers. I'm really happy I got an answer to this question. My instructor said she'd never really thought about it before and I wasn't sure where to go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, if $M$ is the Cantor set, then $M$ and $M \times M$ are homeomorphic.

The same holds if we take $M=\Bbb Q$ or $M=\Bbb P$ (the irrationals), in their usual topology inherited from $\Bbb R$.

A one-dimensional example is $M$ equal to the [Erdős space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erd%C5%91s_space), also homeomorphic to its square (and completely metrisable and separable too, as all previous examples).

Many infinite-dimensional examples exist, like $\ell^2$ and $\Bbb R^{\Bbb N}$ (in the product topology); though these examples are also topologically the same (homeomorphic).

A non-separable metric example is $\ell^\infty$, e.g.

Comment: What notion of dimension is being used in that example of Erdös?

Comment: @LeeMosher dim, Ind and Ind are the same for separable metric spaces. So any of the standard topological dimensions.